# Facebook PHP API post an backdated element to page

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have read the API description on `https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.12/post`.

And I try to create an backdated post over the php facebook api.
I tried it on this way.

```
$linkData = [
         'link' => "https://www.example.com/article.php?id=1",
         'message' => "My Test",
         'created_time' => "2018-05-01T18:06:28+0000",
         'description' => "My description",
        ];
```

But it don't work. It is allways posted with the actual time and not given in `creted_time`.

Comment: Have you tried using the same date value in `updated_time`?

Comment: Yes I also tried updated_time but it also don't work.

Comment: Or how I must post the time I want? "2018-05-01 18:06:28"?

Answer (score 2):

Ok after long searching I found self the answer. It seems that `updated_time` and `created_time` is out of date. Working is now over api `backdated_time`. Attention, if necessary, observe the time difference!

Comment: Thanks for this. I've been looking on how to do this for ages!